# How to get the leaflet-control-layers-toggle icon to show with angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

Following instructions as per Layers Simple example on tut: http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/layers-simple

Inclusion of below successfully loads on page, yet icon in top right to toggle different layers is not produced. No direction provided on repo as to ensure that it is produced.

```
$scope.layers = {
    baselayers: {
        osm: {
            name: 'OpenStreetMap',
            url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            type: 'xyz'
        },
        mapbox_light: {
            name: 'Foo',
            url: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            type: 'xyz'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Where is your leaflet images directory?can you show us a demo site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a bug in the current 0.8.1 version of angular-leaflet-directive. Today I had the same problem. Going back to 0.7.15 and Layer Control is visible again.